# Idiomatic way manage persistent data stores in Docker

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

**Setting**

I have 10+ gigs of images on my local machine, there could be terabytes of images in the future, in which case it will be hosted on, ie, aws. The images will be served to some website, and also be inputs for a machine learning pipeline.

Right now I am developing on my local machine. The source code is at `path/to/src`, and the data is at `path/to/images`. I have already set up a `Docker` environment with `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM bamos/openface
ADD . /face-off
WORKDIR /face-off    
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt    
EXPOSE 5000    
CMD [ "python", "app.py" ]
```

And `docker-compose` file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    image: face-off-web
    command: python app.py
    ports:
        - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
        - .:/face-off
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

**Problem**

Since I am developing in the `Docker` container, I would need to access all images in `path/to/images`. For now let's keep it simple and say I read images using pre specified path to disk.  I think my options are:

1. One obvious way is to move all the images to `path/to/src`, but this seems dirty to me.
2. Another possibility is to `ADD` the directory in the `Dockerfile`. So then I would need to move both directories to `path/to/project`, where the `Dockerfile` would be located. And then move the src to `path/to/project/src` and data to `path/to/project/data`. But again this smells a lot like option 1.
3. Bring the data in somehow using `docker-compose`. I do not know how to do this right now, despite reading the docs on `docker volume`.

What is the idiomatic way to handle this problem? If the way is option 3, could someone explain how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 3. Bring the data in somehow using docker-compose. I do not know how to do this right now, despite reading the docs on docker volume.

For your use case you want to mount a host path into your container, much like you already do with your project working dir. Just add another line for the images:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    image: face-off-web
    command: python app.py
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - .:/face-off
      - /images/on/host:/path/in/container
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

On a side note, either use [build](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#build) or [image](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#image) not both.

Comment: when I do that I am getting: "ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml' service 'volumes' doesn't have any configuration options. All top level keys in your docker-compose.yml must map to a dictionary of configuration options."

Comment: Doublecheck the indentation, currently docker-compose assumes `volumes` is a service,  I only posted a snippet of your docker-compose.yml, I assumed the `-  .:/face-off` would be enough of a reference.

Comment: Ah so I am on version 1.6.0, even though in my compose file it says version 2. when you say current do you mean version 2 or 3?

Comment: No, I meant your `docker-compose.yml` is currently wrong. I updated my answer with a complete example based on your initial `docker-compose.yml`. Hopefully a bit clearer now.

Comment: Ah I see, it's funny when I do that, I specified using both relative path on host and absolute path, but when I run the container with `docker run -it face-off-web bash`, and I `cd` around, I cannot find it anywhere?

Comment: FYI the data volume is not in the same directory as the docker-compose file, via relative path it is at ../../data

Comment: Try `docker-compose run web bash`, invoking just docker will not read the container config of your `docker-compose.yml`. Using relative paths should be fine with docker-compose, `~/my_images` (relative path based on current user home dir) is also supported.

Comment: Does `docker-compose run web bash` only run the web service? For example is `redis` not running?

Comment: Might want to look into [depends_on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#depends_on). ;) If you haven't already, you really should work through the [compose file reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/) while experimenting a bit.